# How to configure Postfix to relay all incoming mails to my Python script Without checking if user exists on the system?

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I want to configure my Postfix server as accepting all incoming mails to any arbitrary users who don't have to exist on the system, say example@mydomain.com. Now Postfix says, User unknown in local recipient table. What I want is to accept this e-mail without rejecting it and pipe it to my python script. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
luser_relay - Optional catch-all destination for unknown `local(8)` recipients.
```

Add the following to your `main.cf`.

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
#...
#...
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, mydomain.com
local_recipient_maps =
luser_relay = catchall
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
#...
#...
```

and the following to your `aliases` file.

```
#/etc/aliases
catchall:  |/path/to/your/python_script.py
```

Run the following commands

```
postalias /etc/aliases
service postfix reload
```

and you can test the setup by following command

```
echo "test email"|mail -s 'Test email' unknown@mydomain.com
```

Emails to unknown users will be delivered to the python script. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @clement. By the way, can I somehow store that mail as file onto disk without any external script usage. I want to do it with only Postfix configuration. Is it possible ?

Comment: Ya just change the alias file to `catchall:   /path/to/file` and run `postalias /etc/aliases`. All incoming mails will be appended to the file.

Comment: But I want to save as different files. Each mail should correpond to a file.

Comment: Then redirect mails of `catchall` (`catchall: someuser`) to an UNIX user and configure postfix to perform `Maildir` delivery (`home_mailbox = Maildir/`). Every mail will be delivered to a separate file in `/home/someuser/Maildir/`. Or you can write a small python script to write every incoming mail to a separate file.

Comment: Thanks mate. I think it is a good idea to write a python script. Because you mentioned that Postfix will write each mail to user's directory however as I said above those users dont need to exist in the system.

Comment: When my script gets error, Postfix directly send error information to message sender even about the line number of script where error occured. I dont want sender to know error of my script. How can I prevent Postfix from sending this error. Thanks.

Comment: Until you fix the script errors, you can set `soft_bounce = yes` to prevent mails from bouncing to the senders. More about it http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#soft_bounce

Comment: Tip: the script is executed under user nobody by default - you can change it using main.cf option default_privs.